# hibernate exception: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1

Tags: java, hibernate

When I tried to save booking to DB, I got `StaleStateException`. In my case,i have a booking entity, bookingNo is primary key while it is not auto increment. So my logic is:

1. Generate booking no and set it to booking.
2. Call `session.save()`.

By the way,I am using hibernate3 + spring + MySql5.5 and run it in tomcat6,For more detail,please see my coding and log:

Booking Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="booking")
public class Booking extends BaseModel{

    public Booking(){
    }
    @Id
    @Column(length=50)
    private String bookingNo;
    @Column(length=50,nullable=false)
    private String bookedBy;
    @Column(length=1,nullable=false)
    private String status;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Date createDate;
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private Date bookingDate;
```

Booking DAO save function

```
@Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED,isolation=Isolation.DEFAULT)
    public Object save(Object object) {
        logger.debug("save() start,save booking["+object+"] to DB");
        Booking booking = (Booking)object;
        String bookingNo;
        //Step 1:Check if booking no is empty,if empty,generate booking no by customer first
        if(booking.getBookingNo() == null || booking.getBookingNo().trim().isEmpty()){
            logger.debug("save(),find booking no is empty,will generate booking no first");
                bookingNo = (String) generateBookingNo(booking.getCustomer());
                //Set generated booking no to booking
                booking.setBookingNo(bookingNo);
        }
        //Step 2:Get hibernate session
        Session session = sf.getCurrentSession();
        logger.debug("save(),get session and start save booking");
        //Step 3:Save booking
         session.save(booking);
        logger.debug("After save booking,the booking is ["+booking+"]");
        return booking;

}
```

When my struts2 action invoke the save function to save booking,it will got following error

```
13:23:32,703 ERROR AbstractBatcher:51 - Exception executing batch: 
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatcher.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
    at com.chailie.booking.dao.impl.booking.BookingDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$abf7a248.save(<generated>)
    at com.chailie.booking.control.BookingAction.save(BookingAction.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:270)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.chailie.booking.interceptor.InitToDoItemInterceptor.doIntercept(InitToDoItemInterceptor.java:51)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Seems  occur this error when proxy tried to commit transaction in the end of save function,but i don't know what lead to this problem,does anyone could tell me why i will have this issue?
Ps:If you need  more coding or log,please let me know,i will post it according to your requirement

More hibernate log in debug level

```
22:46:55,768 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:358 - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
22:46:55,768 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:358 - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
22:46:55,769 DEBUG SQL:393 - insert into dpac_todoitem (assignedBy, assignedDate, assignedTo, bookingNo, cancelledBy, cancelledDate, completedBy, completedDate, createDate, serviceCode, serviceDesc, status, timestamp, actDeliveredPkg, actDeliveredTime, actDispatchedTime, estDeliveredTime, sequence) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
22:46:55,769 DEBUG SQL:393 - insert into dpac_todoitem (assignedBy, assignedDate, assignedTo, bookingNo, cancelledBy, cancelledDate, completedBy, completedDate, createDate, serviceCode, serviceDesc, status, timestamp, actDeliveredPkg, actDeliveredTime, actDispatchedTime, estDeliveredTime, sequence) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
22:46:55,770 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:476 - preparing statement
22:46:55,770 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:476 - preparing statement
22:46:55,771 DEBUG AbstractEntityPersister:1942 - Dehydrating entity: [com.chailie.booking.model.todo.DPAC#425988]
22:46:55,771 DEBUG AbstractEntityPersister:1942 - Dehydrating entity: [com.chailie.booking.model.todo.DPAC#425988]
22:46:55,772 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'chailieyang' to parameter: 1
22:46:55,772 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'chailieyang' to parameter: 1
22:46:55,773 DEBUG TimestampType:80 - binding '2013-04-29 00:00:00' to parameter: 2
22:46:55,773 DEBUG TimestampType:80 - binding '2013-04-29 00:00:00' to parameter: 2
22:46:55,774 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'chailieyang' to parameter: 3
22:46:55,774 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'chailieyang' to parameter: 3
22:46:55,775 DEBUG StringType:73 - binding null to parameter: 4
22:46:55,775 DEBUG StringType:73 - binding null to parameter: 4
22:46:55,775 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding '' to parameter: 5
22:46:55,775 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding '' to parameter: 5
22:46:55,778 DEBUG TimestampType:73 - binding null to parameter: 6
22:46:55,778 DEBUG TimestampType:73 - binding null to parameter: 6
22:46:55,778 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding '' to parameter: 7
22:46:55,778 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding '' to parameter: 7
22:46:55,779 DEBUG TimestampType:73 - binding null to parameter: 8
22:46:55,779 DEBUG TimestampType:73 - binding null to parameter: 8
22:46:55,780 DEBUG TimestampType:73 - binding null to parameter: 9
22:46:55,780 DEBUG TimestampType:73 - binding null to parameter: 9
22:46:55,780 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'DPAC' to parameter: 10
22:46:55,780 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'DPAC' to parameter: 10
22:46:55,781 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'DPAC' to parameter: 11
22:46:55,781 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'DPAC' to parameter: 11
22:46:55,781 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'PENDING' to parameter: 12
22:46:55,781 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'PENDING' to parameter: 12
22:46:55,782 DEBUG TimestampType:80 - binding '2013-04-29 22:46:55' to parameter: 13
22:46:55,782 DEBUG TimestampType:80 - binding '2013-04-29 22:46:55' to parameter: 13
22:46:55,783 DEBUG IntegerType:73 - binding null to parameter: 14
22:46:55,783 DEBUG IntegerType:73 - binding null to parameter: 14
22:46:55,784 DEBUG TimestampType:73 - binding null to parameter: 15
22:46:55,784 DEBUG TimestampType:73 - binding null to parameter: 15
22:46:55,784 DEBUG TimestampType:73 - binding null to parameter: 16
22:46:55,784 DEBUG TimestampType:73 - binding null to parameter: 16
22:46:55,785 DEBUG TimestampType:73 - binding null to parameter: 17
22:46:55,785 DEBUG TimestampType:73 - binding null to parameter: 17
22:46:55,785 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '425988' to parameter: 18
22:46:55,785 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '425988' to parameter: 18
22:46:55,786 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:44 - Executing batch size: 1
22:46:55,786 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:44 - Executing batch size: 1
22:46:55,787 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:366 - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
22:46:55,787 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:366 - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
22:46:55,788 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:525 - closing statement
22:46:55,788 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:525 - closing statement
22:46:55,789 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1090 - Inserting collection: [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking.parts#SAMSUNG-100003]
22:46:55,789 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1090 - Inserting collection: [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking.parts#SAMSUNG-100003]
22:46:55,790 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:358 - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
22:46:55,790 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:358 - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
22:46:55,791 DEBUG SQL:393 - update part set bookingNo=? where sequence=?
22:46:55,791 DEBUG SQL:393 - update part set bookingNo=? where sequence=?
22:46:55,791 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:476 - preparing statement
22:46:55,791 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:476 - preparing statement
22:46:55,793 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100003' to parameter: 1
22:46:55,793 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100003' to parameter: 1
22:46:55,794 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '8' to parameter: 2
22:46:55,794 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '8' to parameter: 2
22:46:55,794 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1172 - done inserting collection: 1 rows inserted
22:46:55,794 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1172 - done inserting collection: 1 rows inserted
22:46:55,795 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1090 - Inserting collection: [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking.toDoItems#SAMSUNG-100003]
22:46:55,795 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1090 - Inserting collection: [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking.toDoItems#SAMSUNG-100003]
22:46:55,796 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:44 - Executing batch size: 1
22:46:55,796 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:44 - Executing batch size: 1
22:46:55,797 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:366 - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
22:46:55,797 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:366 - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
22:46:55,798 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:525 - closing statement
22:46:55,798 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:525 - closing statement
22:46:55,799 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:358 - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
22:46:55,799 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:358 - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
22:46:55,800 DEBUG SQL:393 - update todoitem set bookingNo=? where sequence=?
22:46:55,800 DEBUG SQL:393 - update todoitem set bookingNo=? where sequence=?
22:46:55,800 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:476 - preparing statement
22:46:55,800 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:476 - preparing statement
22:46:55,801 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100003' to parameter: 1
22:46:55,801 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100003' to parameter: 1
22:46:55,802 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '425984' to parameter: 2
22:46:55,802 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '425984' to parameter: 2
22:46:55,803 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:222 - reusing prepared statement
22:46:55,803 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:222 - reusing prepared statement
22:46:55,803 DEBUG SQL:393 - update todoitem set bookingNo=? where sequence=?
22:46:55,803 DEBUG SQL:393 - update todoitem set bookingNo=? where sequence=?
22:46:55,804 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100003' to parameter: 1
22:46:55,804 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100003' to parameter: 1
22:46:55,805 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '425985' to parameter: 2
22:46:55,805 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '425985' to parameter: 2
22:46:55,805 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:222 - reusing prepared statement
22:46:55,805 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:222 - reusing prepared statement
22:46:55,806 DEBUG SQL:393 - update todoitem set bookingNo=? where sequence=?
22:46:55,806 DEBUG SQL:393 - update todoitem set bookingNo=? where sequence=?
22:46:55,807 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100003' to parameter: 1
22:46:55,807 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100003' to parameter: 1
22:46:55,807 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '425986' to parameter: 2
22:46:55,807 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '425986' to parameter: 2
22:46:55,808 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:222 - reusing prepared statement
22:46:55,808 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:222 - reusing prepared statement
22:46:55,808 DEBUG SQL:393 - update todoitem set bookingNo=? where sequence=?
22:46:55,808 DEBUG SQL:393 - update todoitem set bookingNo=? where sequence=?
22:46:55,809 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100003' to parameter: 1
22:46:55,809 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100003' to parameter: 1
22:46:55,810 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '425987' to parameter: 2
22:46:55,810 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '425987' to parameter: 2
22:46:55,810 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:222 - reusing prepared statement
22:46:55,810 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:222 - reusing prepared statement
22:46:55,811 DEBUG SQL:393 - update todoitem set bookingNo=? where sequence=?
22:46:55,811 DEBUG SQL:393 - update todoitem set bookingNo=? where sequence=?
22:46:55,812 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100003' to parameter: 1
22:46:55,812 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100003' to parameter: 1
22:46:55,812 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '425988' to parameter: 2
22:46:55,812 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '425988' to parameter: 2
22:46:55,813 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1172 - done inserting collection: 5 rows inserted
22:46:55,813 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1172 - done inserting collection: 5 rows inserted
22:46:55,814 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:44 - Executing batch size: 5
22:46:55,814 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:44 - Executing batch size: 5
22:46:55,817 ERROR AbstractBatcher:51 - Exception executing batch: 
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

Comment: Why you don't set other booking class properties that are marked as nullable=false? Only bookingNo is set.

Comment: In your codelet I can't see any problem. Could you post the log of the executed statement, for example with `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` in your hibernate.cfg? It is important to see the actual value for bookingNo, which you can't see in that log. Best you use a tool like `log4jdbc` to make the parameters visible. As a replacement you can print `bookingNo`in your code. Does any database row for this id exist? (Do `SELECT * FROM booking WHERE bookingNo=...` in SQL.)

Comment: Bad news,the log over 30k character,so i can just  post a part of them,please see it,thank you

Comment: Generally, the reason of the exception is better descriped by the caused by statements on stack trace. Can you post full exception stack trace ?

Comment: I wish i could post the full exception stack trace or log,but the stackflow limit the number of words,that means i can't post full log for you

Comment: But if necessary,can you give me your email?because  i could send my complete log for you via email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While change todoitem inheritance strategy to JOINED as following,then problem gone

```
@Entity
@Table(name="todoitem")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class ToDoItem extends BaseModel{
```