# Hibernate one to many:"many" side record's foreign key is updated to null automatically

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I defined two entity as following
1.Booking

```
@Entity
@Table(name="booking")
public class Booking extends BaseModel{
    ..
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="bookingNo")
    private List<Part>parts = new ArrayList<Part>();
  ...
```

2.Part

```
@Entity
@Table(name="part")
public class Part extends BaseModel{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer sequence;
    @Column(length=50)
    private String bookingNo;
```

Now my issue is at first i saved one booking with two part,then in view(JSP),i update this booking and added a new part ,finally i will save this booking again with the new part which create at second time.if everything is okay,i think in DB,it should have three part,yes,it really have three part in DB,two are saved at first time and the third part is saved at second time.but what make me surprised is the first two part's foreign key "bookingNo" is updated to null. i am using hibernate's saveOrUpdate API.Is this because of when i save booking for second time,there is only one part under that booking,such that hibernate would regard others parts(the two part that saved at first time) are deleted by default?
please see my log ,it has below log:
**update part set bookingNo=null where bookingNo=?** when save booking

```
21:41:02,476 DEBUG BookingDAO:65 - save(),get session and start save booking
21:41:02,478 DEBUG VersionValue:44 - version unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
21:41:02,479 DEBUG IdentifierValue:77 - id unsaved-value strategy UNDEFINED
21:41:02,480 DEBUG AbstractEntityPersister:1004 - Getting current persistent state for: [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking#SAMSUNG-100002]
21:41:02,482 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:358 - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
21:41:02,483 DEBUG SQL:393 - select booking_.bookingNo, booking_.bookedBy as bookedBy0_, booking_.bookingDate as bookingD3_0_, booking_.businessService as business4_0_, booking_.cargoType as cargoType0_, booking_.consignee as consignee0_, booking_.consigneeAddress as consigne7_0_, booking_.consigneeCity as consigne8_0_, booking_.consigneeCountry as consigne9_0_, booking_.consigneeName as consign10_0_, booking_.consigneePostal as consign11_0_, booking_.consigneeState as consign12_0_, booking_.createDate as createDate0_, booking_.customer as customer0_, booking_.customerAddress as custome15_0_, booking_.customerCity as custome16_0_, booking_.customerCountry as custome17_0_, booking_.customerName as custome18_0_, booking_.customerPostal as custome19_0_, booking_.customerState as custome20_0_, booking_.frtPayTerm as frtPayTerm0_, booking_.incoterms as incoterms0_, booking_.otherPayTerm as otherPa23_0_, booking_.remark as remark0_, booking_.serviceLevel as service25_0_, booking_.shipper as shipper0_, booking_.shipperAddress as shipper27_0_, booking_.shipperCity as shipper28_0_, booking_.shipperCountry as shipper29_0_, booking_.shipperName as shipper30_0_, booking_.shipperPostal as shipper31_0_, booking_.shipperState as shipper32_0_, booking_.status as status0_, booking_.timestamp as timestamp0_ from booking booking_ where booking_.bookingNo=?
21:41:02,487 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:476 - preparing statement
21:41:02,489 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100002' to parameter: 1
21:41:02,492 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning 'chailieyang' as column: bookedBy0_
21:41:02,494 DEBUG TimestampType:122 - returning '2013-06-06 00:00:00' as column: bookingD3_0_
21:41:02,496 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning 'sea' as column: business4_0_
21:41:02,497 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning '' as column: cargoType0_
21:41:02,498 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning 'LENOVO' as column: consignee0_
21:41:02,500 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning '' as column: consigne7_0_
21:41:02,501 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning '' as column: consigne8_0_
21:41:02,502 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning 'USA' as column: consigne9_0_
21:41:02,503 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning 'Zhao Yang,Bei JIng China' as column: consign10_0_
21:41:02,504 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning '' as column: consign11_0_
21:41:02,505 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning 'ALABAMA' as column: consign12_0_
21:41:02,506 DEBUG TimestampType:122 - returning '2013-05-02 21:39:03' as column: createDate0_
21:41:02,507 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning 'SAMSUNG' as column: customer0_
21:41:02,508 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning '' as column: custome15_0_
21:41:02,509 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning '' as column: custome16_0_
21:41:02,510 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning 'USA' as column: custome17_0_
21:41:02,511 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning 'Samsung CO,Korea' as column: custome18_0_
21:41:02,512 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning '' as column: custome19_0_
21:41:02,514 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning 'ALABAMA' as column: custome20_0_
21:41:02,514 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning '' as column: frtPayTerm0_
21:41:02,515 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning '' as column: incoterms0_
21:41:02,516 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning '' as column: otherPa23_0_
21:41:02,517 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning '' as column: remark0_
21:41:02,518 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning '' as column: service25_0_
21:41:02,519 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning 'SAMSUNG' as column: shipper0_
21:41:02,520 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning '' as column: shipper27_0_
21:41:02,521 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning '' as column: shipper28_0_
21:41:02,522 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning 'USA' as column: shipper29_0_
21:41:02,524 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning 'Samsung CO,Korea' as column: shipper30_0_
21:41:02,527 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning '' as column: shipper31_0_
21:41:02,528 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning 'ALABAMA' as column: shipper32_0_
21:41:02,531 DEBUG StringType:122 - returning 'N' as column: status0_
21:41:02,532 DEBUG TimestampType:122 - returning '2013-05-02 21:39:49' as column: timestamp0_
21:41:02,533 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:366 - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
21:41:02,534 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:525 - closing statement
21:41:02,535 DEBUG AbstractSaveEventListener:498 - detached instance of: com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking
21:41:02,536 DEBUG DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener:203 - updating detached instance
21:41:02,537 DEBUG DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener:249 - updating [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking#SAMSUNG-100002]
21:41:02,538 DEBUG ReattachVisitor:60 - collection dereferenced while transient [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking.parts#SAMSUNG-100002]
21:41:02,539 DEBUG ReattachVisitor:60 - collection dereferenced while transient [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking.toDoItems#SAMSUNG-100002]
21:41:02,540 DEBUG DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener:298 - updating [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking#SAMSUNG-100002]
21:41:02,541 DEBUG Cascade:115 - processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking
21:41:02,542 DEBUG Cascade:291 - cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking.parts
21:41:02,543 DEBUG CascadingAction:216 - cascading to saveOrUpdate: com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Part
21:41:02,545 DEBUG AbstractSaveEventListener:489 - transient instance of: com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Part
21:41:02,546 DEBUG DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener:161 - saving transient instance
21:41:02,547 DEBUG AbstractSaveEventListener:152 - saving [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Part#<null>]
21:41:02,548 DEBUG AbstractSaveEventListener:240 - executing insertions
21:41:02,550 DEBUG Versioning:42 - Seeding: 2013-05-02 21:41:02.549
21:41:02,552 DEBUG AbstractSaveEventListener:289 - executing identity-insert immediately
21:41:02,555 DEBUG AbstractEntityPersister:2094 - Inserting entity: com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Part (native id)
21:41:02,557 DEBUG AbstractEntityPersister:2096 - Version: 2013-05-02 21:41:02.549
21:41:02,559 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:358 - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
21:41:02,563 DEBUG SQL:393 - insert into part (bookingNo, createDate, partNo, poNo, qtyReceived, qtyShipped, qtyUnit, timestamp) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
21:41:02,566 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:476 - preparing statement
21:41:02,570 DEBUG AbstractEntityPersister:1942 - Dehydrating entity: [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Part#<null>]
21:41:02,572 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100002' to parameter: 1
21:41:02,574 DEBUG TimestampType:73 - binding null to parameter: 2
21:41:02,577 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding '' to parameter: 3
21:41:02,579 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding '9999' to parameter: 4
21:41:02,587 DEBUG IntegerType:73 - binding null to parameter: 5
21:41:02,590 DEBUG IntegerType:73 - binding null to parameter: 6
21:41:02,591 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding '' to parameter: 7
21:41:02,595 DEBUG TimestampType:80 - binding '2013-05-02 21:41:02' to parameter: 8
21:41:02,598 DEBUG IdentifierGeneratorFactory:37 - Natively generated identity: 4
21:41:02,600 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:366 - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
21:41:02,602 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:525 - closing statement
21:41:02,605 DEBUG Cascade:306 - done cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking.parts
21:41:02,606 DEBUG Cascade:150 - done processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking
21:41:02,608 DEBUG BookingDAO:68 - After save booking,the booking is [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking@5774a1e3]
21:41:02,611 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:103 - commit
21:41:02,612 DEBUG SessionImpl:337 - automatically flushing session
21:41:02,614 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:58 - flushing session
21:41:02,615 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:111 - processing flush-time cascades
21:41:02,616 DEBUG Cascade:115 - processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking
21:41:02,618 DEBUG Cascade:291 - cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking.parts
21:41:02,619 DEBUG CascadingAction:216 - cascading to saveOrUpdate: com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Part
21:41:02,620 DEBUG AbstractSaveEventListener:463 - persistent instance of: com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Part
21:41:02,621 DEBUG DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener:105 - ignoring persistent instance
21:41:02,623 DEBUG DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener:142 - object already associated with session: [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Part#4]
21:41:02,625 DEBUG Cascade:306 - done cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for collection: com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking.parts
21:41:02,626 DEBUG Cascade:150 - done processing cascade ACTION_SAVE_UPDATE for: com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking
21:41:02,627 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:154 - dirty checking collections
21:41:02,628 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:171 - Flushing entities and processing referenced collections
21:41:02,630 DEBUG WrapVisitor:87 - Wrapped collection in role: com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking.parts
21:41:02,631 DEBUG Collections:176 - Collection found: [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking.parts#SAMSUNG-100002], was: [<unreferenced>] (initialized)
21:41:02,633 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:210 - Processing unreferenced collections
21:41:02,635 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:224 - Scheduling collection removes/(re)creates/updates
21:41:02,636 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:85 - Flushed: 0 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 2 objects
21:41:02,637 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:91 - Flushed: 1 (re)creations, 0 updates, 2 removals to 1 collections
21:41:02,638 DEBUG Printer:83 - listing entities:
21:41:02,639 DEBUG Printer:90 - com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Part{timestamp=2013-05-02 21:41:02, poNo=9999, qtyShipped=null, partNo=, sequence=4, bookingNo=SAMSUNG-100002, qtyReceived=null, createDate=null, qtyUnit=}
21:41:02,641 DEBUG Printer:90 - com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking{remark=, consignee=LENOVO, customerCity=, customerState=ALABAMA, parts=[com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Part#4], serviceLevel=, customer=SAMSUNG, otherPayTerm=, consigneeCity=, consigneePostal=, timestamp=2013-05-02 21:39:49, businessService=sea, shipperName=Samsung CO,Korea, customerCountry=USA, cargoType=, shipperCity=, createDate=2013-05-02 21:39:03, customerPostal=, shipperPostal=, customerName=Samsung CO,Korea, consigneeName=Zhao Yang,Bei JIng China, bookingDate=2013-06-06 00:00:00, consigneeAddress=, incoterms=, status=N, shipperCountry=USA, shipper=SAMSUNG, bookingNo=SAMSUNG-100002, shipperState=ALABAMA, shipperAddress=, toDoItems=null, consigneeCountry=USA, customerAddress=, frtPayTerm=, consigneeState=ALABAMA, bookedBy=chailieyang}
21:41:02,644 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:290 - executing flush
21:41:02,646 DEBUG ConnectionManager:463 - registering flush begin
21:41:02,647 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1010 - Deleting collection: [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking.parts#SAMSUNG-100002]
21:41:02,648 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:358 - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
21:41:02,650 DEBUG SQL:393 - update part set bookingNo=null where bookingNo=?
21:41:02,651 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:476 - preparing statement
21:41:02,653 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100002' to parameter: 1
21:41:02,655 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1067 - done deleting collection
21:41:02,656 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1010 - Deleting collection: [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking.toDoItems#SAMSUNG-100002]
21:41:02,657 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:44 - Executing batch size: 1
21:41:02,660 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:366 - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
21:41:02,661 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:525 - closing statement
21:41:02,663 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:358 - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
21:41:02,664 DEBUG SQL:393 - update todoitem set bookingNo=null where bookingNo=?
21:41:02,666 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:476 - preparing statement
21:41:02,668 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100002' to parameter: 1
21:41:02,669 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1067 - done deleting collection
21:41:02,670 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:44 - Executing batch size: 1
21:41:02,672 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:366 - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
21:41:02,673 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:525 - closing statement
21:41:02,675 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1090 - Inserting collection: [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking.parts#SAMSUNG-100002]
21:41:02,677 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:358 - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
21:41:02,679 DEBUG SQL:393 - update part set bookingNo=? where sequence=?
21:41:02,682 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:476 - preparing statement
21:41:02,685 DEBUG StringType:80 - binding 'SAMSUNG-100002' to parameter: 1
21:41:02,687 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '4' to parameter: 2
21:41:02,688 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1172 - done inserting collection: 1 rows inserted
21:41:02,689 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:44 - Executing batch size: 1
21:41:02,692 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:366 - about to close PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 1, globally: 1)
21:41:02,694 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:525 - closing statement
21:41:02,695 DEBUG ConnectionManager:472 - registering flush end
21:41:02,696 DEBUG AbstractFlushingEventListener:321 - post flush
21:41:02,697 DEBUG JDBCContext:201 - before transaction completion
21:41:02,698 DEBUG SessionImpl:393 - before transaction completion
21:41:02,889 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:193 - re-enabling autocommit
21:41:02,891 DEBUG JDBCTransaction:116 - committed JDBC Connection
21:41:02,893 DEBUG JDBCContext:215 - after transaction completion
21:41:02,895 DEBUG ConnectionManager:296 - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
21:41:02,896 DEBUG SessionImpl:422 - after transaction completion
21:41:02,897 DEBUG SessionImpl:353 - automatically closing session
21:41:02,898 DEBUG SessionImpl:273 - closing session
21:41:02,899 DEBUG ConnectionManager:374 - performing cleanup
21:41:02,900 DEBUG ConnectionManager:435 - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
21:41:02,901 DEBUG JDBCContext:215 - after transaction completion
21:41:02,902 DEBUG ConnectionManager:296 - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
21:41:02,904 DEBUG SessionImpl:422 - after transaction completion
21:41:02,905 DEBUG SessionImpl:273 - closing session
21:41:02,906 DEBUG BookingUtil:298 - initBooking() start with booking [com.chailie.booking.model.booking.Booking@5774a1e3],user [User [userName=chailieyang, loginIp=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]]
21:41:02,907 DEBUG BookingUtil:111 - initToDoItems start with todoitems [null]
21:41:02,918 DEBUG BookingUtil:75 - initToDoItems() start,init complete todoitem
21:41:02,922 DEBUG ServletDispatcherResult:68 - Forwarding to location newbooking.jsp
```

Comment: is your foreign key is a auto increment field and set in the DB properly?

Comment: Sorry,forgot told you the foreign key "bookingNo" is not a auto increment field,i generated it by myself and set it to Booking manually.

Comment: However you marked your foreign key as GeneratedValue. One reason would be this why your code fails. Can you post your DAO codes?

Comment: What do you mean of "marked your foreign key as GeneratedValue"?You could see my DAO from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271934/hibernate-exception-batch-update-returned-unexpected-row-count-from-update-0

Comment: Your Booking class has OneToMany relation on your Part class ,where the PK of Part and FK of the relation build on sequence variable. sequence is annotated GeneratedValue where there is no Generated value strategy in DB since the field is not an auto - increment field in DB. Can you make sequence field auto-increment in DB and try it again? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html

Comment: If you want to set ID field explicitly you can remove GeneratedValue annotation instead of making sequence field auto-increment.

Comment: In my case,the booking's PK is bookingNo ,but it is a string and generated by customer+sequence.such that i can't make it auto-increment.i mean after all,the PK is a string,Do you mean when use hibernate one to many,the one side entity's PK has to use auto increment?

Comment: Yes,Maybe you are right,I will change the primary key "bookingNo" to auto increment and try again.it seems most of my issues are come from many side entity's FK "bookingNo"

Comment: But anyway,it should have the case of one side entity's PK is manually setting but instead of auto increment,right?

Comment: GeneratedValue expects values to be generated by DB. Can you remove GeneratedValue annotation?

Comment: Yes,But i didn't use GenerateValue before,i have said that bookingNo is manually setting and just have @Id annotation,but after i changed booking's FK to auto increment,now at leat i could save booking and part successful,but still have this issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271934/hibernate-exception-batch-update-returned-unexpected-row-count-from-update-0

Comment: Please see my log.In my case,the one side is booking and many side is 
todoitem,e.g
@JoinColumn(name="bookingSeq")
private List <ToDoItem>toDoItems = new ArrayList< ToDoItem>();
However,in this List todoitems,it is some of specified ToDoItem which inherited from todoitem.
e.g pdas_todoitem.so 
23:07:29,951 DEBUG SQL:393 - insert into pdas_todoitem (assignedBy, assignedDate, assignedTo, bookingNo, bookingSeq, ...
.....
23:07:29,978 DEBUG SQL:393 - update todoitem set bookingSeq=? where sequence=?
23:07:29,979 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:476 - preparing statement

Comment: 23:07:29,980 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '8' to parameter: 1
23:07:29,981 DEBUG IntegerType:80 - binding '3' to parameter: 2
23:07:29,982 DEBUG AbstractCollectionPersister:1172 - done inserting collection: 1 rows inserted
23:07:29,983 DEBUG AbstractBatcher:44 - Executing batch size: 1
23:07:29,984 ERROR AbstractBatcher:51 - Exception executing batch: 
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
 at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:61)
 at

Comment: Hi erencan,forgot said thanks for you,your suggestion really helped me a lot

Comment: in the end i will post my complate answer :) If you look at the Docs @ID values can be Strings I do not know what is your case http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Id.html

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem is caused by i set part's FK as nullable before,after i specify the FK is not nullable,it won't have that problem anymore,please see my Part entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="part")
public class Part extends BaseModel{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer sequence;
    @Column(length=50,nullable=false,insertable=false,updatable=false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add for others that I was experiencing the same issue and the solution ended up being the lack of `inverse="true"` on my collection elements.

Good article here explaining why [inverse true is a good idea for collections.](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/inverse-true-example-and-explanation/)

Answer (score -1):

<strike>You cannot mix @OneToMany and @JoinColumn annotations.</strike>

The "booking" table cannot have references to the "part" table because there isn't a scalable way of storing many part id's: Does the "booking" table needs to have a "partId" column? if a booking can have many parts, does the part id's need to be stored separated by commas in that column?

Instead, the owning side of the relationship needs to be in the "many" side, in this case the "part" table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="booking")
public class Booking extends BaseModel{
    ..
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="booking")
    private List<Part>parts = new ArrayList<Part>();
    ..
}

@Entity
@Table(name="part")
public class Part extends BaseModel{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer sequence;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(length=50, name="bookingNo")
    private Booking booking;
    ..
}
```

Note the use of the @ManyToOne annotation in the Part entity to indicate that it is the owning side of the relationship. The @OneToMany annotation in the Booking entity needs the parameter "mappedBy", which indicates the field in the "Part" entity annotated with @ManyToOne, and also indicates that the Booking entity is the inverse side of the relationship.

EDIT:

As pointed by erencan, in fact you can mix @OneToMany and @JoinColumn, and the tables will end with the same structure as with using @ManyToOne. 
It seems strange the member variable "bookingNo" in the Part entity, since it is not needed to do the mapping. @ManyToOne could be used to have information about the Booking entity if needed.

Comment: you can mix OneToMany and JoinColumn annotation and there is no need OneToMany annotation for ManyToOne annotation. You can use them depending on your choices.